# WF4 Transactions and Persistence

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, transactionscope

I have a couple of questions about transactions in WF4...

According to this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/aeab2bcd-26c6-49be-8e08-d65ee2688038

> 4) There is an implicit Persistence Point at the end of both the TransactionScope and TransactedReceiveScope activities. The persistence operation is tied to the same transaction (assuming the persistence provider supports transactions which is the case with SqlWorkflowInstanceStore).

I would like to confirm this.. if persistence fails, all the operations made inside the transaction will rollback right?

Another question, can I update promoted properties inside the transaction scope?

thanks in advance!!

Cheers from Argentina!

ps. sorry my english is bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, the transaction will rollback. See below for confirmation:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015936